# How to compile and upload the specific (.cpp + .h) code?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, compile

I have a specific arduino code (no .ino files) https://github.com/justintconroy/MdbBillValidator , which can't be opened by arduino IDE. How can I make & upload this code? I have an arduino 2560 mega.

I've created an empty `MdbBillValidator.ino` file and added these lines:

```
#include "MdbBillValidator.h"

void setup() {

}

void loop() {

}
```

Here is the error message

```
MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_37()’:
MdbSerial.cpp:289:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp:291:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_52()’:
MdbSerial.cpp:314:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp:316:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_55()’:
MdbSerial.cpp:339:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp:341:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
MdbSerial.cpp: At global scope:
MdbSerial.cpp:554:135: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
MdbSerial.cpp:554:189: error: no matching function for call to ‘MdbSerial::MdbSerial(ring_buffer*, ring_buffer*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)’
MdbSerial.cpp:554:189: note: candidates are:
MdbSerial.cpp:352:1: note: MdbSerial::MdbSerial(ring_buffer*, ring_buffer*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
MdbSerial.cpp:352:1: note:   candidate expects 20 arguments, 19 provided
In file included from MdbSerial.cpp:38:0:
MdbSerial.h:52:7: note: MdbSerial::MdbSerial(const MdbSerial&)
MdbSerial.h:52:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 19 provided
```

Comment: That's a library. You can't just run that code. You can create a new sketch, and place these files in this new sketch's folder. Then `#include` it inside the ino file.

Comment: Hm!

Okay, I'll try to do that!

Comment: @Gerben which files should I include?

Comment: I think `#include "MdbBillValidator.h"`

Comment: don't work. compilation error

Comment: Let me get my crystal ball, to see the error message.

Comment: Oh, I've added it. Pls review the question again. Any ideas?

Comment: What folder are the library files living in? How many files from that repository did you download, and what folder do they live in? All the error report is telling me is that the library can't find the files it depends on.

Comment: I've cloned a file to the directory, and create an `MdbBillValidator.ino` (as the name of the directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I need to import this code just a simple usual library.