# mega include a library

Tags: library

This question is a little related to this one: [How to compile and upload the specific (.cpp + .h) code?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/how-to-compile-and-upload-the-specific-cpp-h-code)

I've installed [MdbBillValidator](https://github.com/justintconroy/MdbBillValidator) to my arduino libraries collection. I tried both on ubuntu & windows.

How can I include it? Default inclusion, by arduino ide, was:

```
#include <MdbSerial.h>
#include <wiring_private.h>
#include <MdbBillValidator.h>
#include <MdbMaster.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

void loop() {

}

void setup() {

}
```

And here is error comes in:

```
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_37()’:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:289:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR1B |= (1 << TXB8);
                       ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:291:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR1B &= ~(1 << TXB8);
                        ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_52()’:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:314:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR2B |= (1 << TXB8);
                       ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:316:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR2B &= ~(1 << TXB8);
                        ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp: In function ‘void __vector_55()’:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:339:23: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR3B |= (1 << TXB8);
                       ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:341:24: error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope
       UCSR3B &= ~(1 << TXB8);
                        ^
In file included from /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/iom2560.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/io.h:160,
                 from /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/pgmspace.h:88,
                 from /home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/Arduino.h:8,
                 from /home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:31:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp: At global scope:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:554:135: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
   MdbSerial MdbPort1(&rx_buffer1, &tx_buffer1, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1A, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C, &UDR1, RXEN1, TXEN1, RXCIE1, UDRIE1, U2X1 UCSZ12, UCSZ11, UCSZ10, UPM11, UPM10, UMSEL11, UMSEL10);
                                                                                                                                       ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:554:189: error: no matching function for call to ‘MdbSerial::MdbSerial(ring_buffer*, ring_buffer*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)’
   MdbSerial MdbPort1(&rx_buffer1, &tx_buffer1, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1A, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C, &UDR1, RXEN1, TXEN1, RXCIE1, UDRIE1, U2X1 UCSZ12, UCSZ11, UCSZ10, UPM11, UPM10, UMSEL11, UMSEL10);
                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:554:189: note: candidates are:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:352:1: note: MdbSerial::MdbSerial(ring_buffer*, ring_buffer*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, volatile uint8_t*, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
 MdbSerial::MdbSerial(ring_buffer *rx_buffer, ring_buffer *tx_buffer,
 ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:352:1: note:   candidate expects 20 arguments, 19 provided
In file included from /home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.cpp:38:0:
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.h:52:7: note: MdbSerial::MdbSerial(const MdbSerial&)
 class MdbSerial
       ^
/home/asiniy/sketchbook/libraries/MdbBillValidator/MdbSerial.h:52:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 19 provided
```

What I need to do to avoid this error and get the code worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding this to your program?

```
#define RXB8 1
#define TXB8 0
#define UPE 2
#define OVR 3
#define FE 4
#define UDRE 5
#define RXC 7

#define FRAMING_ERROR (1<<FE)
#define PARITY_ERROR (1<<UPE)
#define DATA_OVERRUN (1<<OVR)
#define DATA_REGISTER_EMPTY (1<<UDRE)
#define RX_COMPLETE (1<<RXC)
```

I found someone with similar code, who had these defines and as your code seems to miss/cannot find something, this might fix it.
Though I'm not sure if these defines apply in your specific implementation. For that I should have to see the code where the error is pointing at.

Comment: Regards, done compiling! What do you think about it? Why author set these values empty?

Comment: He might have had another file, that he didn't upload to github.
You do have an idea of what these values do? Because TXB8 is bit 0 from the register, so instead of using 0, you can use a `define` or definition, which is easier to understand.
Also, you should check the error message when it won't compile.
`error: ‘TXB8’ was not declared in this scope` Which mean that the compiler could't find the variable 'TXB8'. So either missing a variable, out of scope, or missing a define ;D And if you look at the code on that position, you should see what is missing there.

Comment: I asked him at github about this. In general, this library allows to connect mdb bus with PC through arduino

Comment: btw, it's still don't work on windows. I get this: `C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MdbBillValidator\MdbSerial.cpp:554:135: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
   MdbSerial MdbPort1(&rx_buffer1, &tx_buffer1, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1A, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C, &UDR1, RXEN1, TXEN1, RXCIE1, UDRIE1, U2X1 UCSZ12, UCSZ11, UCSZ10, UPM11, UPM10, UMSEL11, UMSEL10);`

Comment: You're sure you have all the `RXEN1, TXEN1, RXCIE1, UDRIE1, U2X1 UCSZ12, UCSZ11, UCSZ10, UPM11, UPM10, UMSEL11, UMSEL10` defined or initialized somewhere? And can you see on what character/position on that line the error is?

Comment: Thanks for helping, this was a typo: https://github.com/justintconroy/MdbBillValidator/pull/4

Comment: Ah I see, yea, it's hard to just see such an error in code you haven't made yourself.
But, the error usually gives a good idea of what is wrong (though it might sound a bit technical) `expected ')' before numeric` means that it simply didn't expect another numeric to come, thus wanted to close the function call (with a ')') before it could take another numeric. But in this case we didn't need a ')' there but a ','... But that's also why I asked for the position/character on the line.